# how to send data no click button by json and jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I send data

I do not want refresh the page

when click button (GO)
i want send data by json

I use this

```
<html>
<head>

  <script>
var n = {A:10, B:12, submit:true};

$.ajax({
url: "ABC.html",
type: "POST",
data : n ,
datatype: "html",
success : function (data) {
alert("Yes");
}

});
  </script>
</head>

<body>
user : <input type='text' name='A'/><br>
user : <input type='text' name='B'/><br>
<input name='submit' type="submit" value='GO' />
</body>
</html>
```

but not send

Comment: put it in `$(function(){//your code});`

Comment: @13ruce1337 in this particular example the DOM is not referenced, so it doesn't need to wait.

Comment: @RUJordan noted and now i think i better understand the use. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see **[$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**  for more

send your dataType as **json** if you want to send data as json

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();//use to prevent default action of submit button
    var n = {A:10, B:12, submit:true};
    $.ajax({
    url: "ABC.html",
    type: "POST",
    data : n ,
    datatype: "json",//use json here
    success : function (data) {
    alert("Yes");
    }

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a event handler and prevent the form sumission:

```
$('[value="GO"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var n = {
        A: 10,
        B: 12,
        submit: true
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "ABC.html",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(n), // converted to json
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Yes");
        }
    });
});
```

The data will now be formatted as json, which you can recieve at your backend